# argparse with multiple optional flags in one dash

Tags: python, argparse

Is it possible to associate multiple flags with a single dash in `argparse` as in this standard Linux argument style?

```
 tar -xvf some_filename.tar
```

Comment: The `OptionParser` in the `optparse` module supports this natively - if options have shorthand versions they can be combined in exactly this way when passed to your script.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This will do the trick. Most likely, you didn't include the short form for each argument.

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='... saves many files together...')
parser.add_argument('--extract', '-x',
                    action='store_true',
                    help='extract files from an archive')
parser.add_argument('--verbose', '-v',
                    action='store_true',
                    help='verbosely list files processed')
parser.add_argument('--file', '-f',
                    # dest='file', -- only needed if the long form isn't first
                    help='use archive file or device ARCHIVE')

args = parser.parse_args()
```

Comment: Derp. I didn't even try it so see if it just worked out-of-the-box. I thought I would have to use some special `add_argument` parameter.

Comment: From the docs, https://docs.python.org/dev/library/argparse.html#option-value-syntax `Several short options can be joined together, using only a single - prefix, as long as only the last option (or none of them) requires a value:`