# Argument flag that is null when not used and default value when used without argument

Tags: python, command-line, argparse

I'm using argparse to parse arguments. I'd like to have a flag that is `NULL` when not used, `foo` when used without an argument, and the argument value when used with an argument.

```
ap = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='test')
ap.add_argument('--bar', action='store_true')
args = ap.parse_args()
```

The above code is what i have currently.

I would like `python test.py` to have `ap.bar=None`, `python test.py --bar` to have `ap.bar=foo`, and `python test.py --bar ctest` to have `ap.bar=ctest`. What would I modify to have this happen?

Comment: There is no such thing as `NULL`. Do you mean `None`?

Comment: This is documented under `nargs='?'`, https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#nargs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming that you mean `None` rather than `NULL`.

You can do:

```
import argparse

ap = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='test')
ap.add_argument('--bar', nargs='?', const='foo')
args = ap.parse_args()

print(args.bar)
```

This gives:

```
$ python3 test.py
None

$ python3 test.py --bar
foo

$ python3 test.py --bar ctest
ctest
```

As a possible mnemonic, the `nargs='?'` syntax (meaning zero or one) is similar to the usage of `?` in regular expressions.

Comment: if I try to run multiple flags with this [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24919310/13112739), then it counts all the other flags as the arguments for the first flag. Is there an easy way to fix this?

Comment: @user760900 Please could you give an example of what command line you want to use, and how you want it to be interpreted.

Comment: I realized it should probably be [a separate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62747802)

Comment: @user760900 Fair enough, I may take a look.