# argparse: nargs with multiple flags in one dash?

Tags: python, command-line, parameter-passing, argparse

If I try running `python test.py -bf` with the below code, I get `bar=f` and `foo=foo1` instead of the desired result (`bar=bar1` and `foo=foo1`). How would I achieve the desired result?

```
import argparse

ap = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='test')
ap.add_argument('--bar', '-b', nargs='?', const='bar1')
ap.add_argument('--foo', '-f', nargs='?', const='foo1')
args = ap.parse_args()
```

Comment: I think you will have to accept it as a limitation that in that case you must do `python test.py -b -f`

Comment: `-bf` only works with a `-b` that has `nargs=0`, i.e. a `store_true` (or `store_const`).  The logic handling `-bf` is not complex enough to handle the '?' case.